# xrandr reporting wrong resolution after booting from script started with upstart

Tags: scripts, upstart, display-resolution, xrandr

I have a script in

```
/home/username/.config/upstart
```

myscript.conf ...

```
description "my startup scripts"
start on desktop-start
exec ~/scripts/startup.sh start
```

that startup script eventually calls another which invokes..

```
H=( `xrandr --current | grep '*' | uniq | awk '{print $1}' | cut -d 'x' -f1`)
V=( `xrandr --current | grep '*' | uniq | awk '{print $1}' | cut -d 'x' -f2`)
```

but my logs have it reporting the wrong resolution.  I believe there is a race condition at startup because if I call the script manually it reports the correct resolution.

Is there a way for me to avoid the race?  Is there another place to call a startup script after all environment variable are loaded?  Is there something else wrong that I'm missing?